# How to prevent repetitive returns for almost same contitions in IF and ELSE?

Tags: javascript

I have a for which loops for X files, if the current file is the file Y i have to skip it if the condition `dcc.payload.v[0].dn === dcc.payload.v[0].sd && dcc.payload.v[0].dn > 1` is true, else i have to make my checks and return the result.

The issue is that after adding that new condition my code even if it's small become very unwatchable..

I would to simplify it in some way, which would be the best way to do so?

```
for (const ruleFile of ruleFiles) {
  if (ruleFile === 'VR-DE-0003.json') {
    if (dcc.payload.v[0].dn === dcc.payload.v[0].sd && dcc.payload.v[0].dn > 1) {
        
    }else {
      const rule = Rule.fromFile(`./data/rules/${ruleFile}`, {
        valueSets,
        validationClock: new Date().toISOString(),
      });
      const result = await rule.evaluateDCC(dcc);
        
      if (result === false) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          nome: dcc.payload.nam.gn,
          cognome: dcc.payload.nam.fn,
          data_nascita: dcc.payload.dob,
          dosi: `${dcc.payload.v[0].dn}/${dcc.payload.v[0].sd}`,
          message: rule.getDescription("it"),
          valid: result,
        });
      } 
    }
  }else {
    const rule = Rule.fromFile(`./data/rules/${ruleFile}`, {
      valueSets,
      validationClock: new Date().toISOString(),
    });
    const result = await rule.evaluateDCC(dcc);
    if (result === false) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        nome: dcc.payload.nam.gn,
        cognome: dcc.payload.nam.fn,
        data_nascita: dcc.payload.dob,
        dosi: `${dcc.payload.v[0].dn}/${dcc.payload.v[0].sd}`,
        message: rule.getDescription("it"),
        valid: result,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, update the title so that it shows what your code does, and not what you intend to change about it. That title is too loose for a site like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce duplicated code, just change the condition:

```js
for (const ruleFile of ruleFiles) {
  if (ruleFile !== 'VR-DE-0003.json') 
    || dcc.payload.v[0].dn !== dcc.payload.v[0].sd
    || dcc.payload.v[0].dn <= 1) {
const rule = Rule.fromFile(`./data/rules/${ruleFile}`, {
        valueSets,
        validationClock: new Date().toISOString(),
      });
      const result = await rule.evaluateDCC(dcc);
        
      if (result === false) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          nome: dcc.payload.nam.gn,
          cognome: dcc.payload.nam.fn,
          data_nascita: dcc.payload.dob,
          dosi: `${dcc.payload.v[0].dn}/${dcc.payload.v[0].sd}`,
          message: rule.getDescription("it"),
          valid: result,
        });
      } 
    }
  }
```